# Discriminant of a polynomial definition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, elementary-functions

Why is the discriminant of a polynomial defined as the product of squared differences of roots? How do I intuitively understand it? Why was this definition chosen?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Nature_of_the_roots) help?

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty so the discriminant just has to be something that is 0, if the 2 or more roots are the same, otherwise it's greater than 0?

Comment: It may be negative, for instance when the polynomial is quadratic with imaginary roots. One reason that you *square* the differences of the roots is that that’s what gives you an answer that’s a polynomial in the coefficients of your (monic) polynomial.

Comment: @Lubin oh yea, thanks, I was wondering how you get a negative discriminant when you have squares everywhere :)

Comment: Sorry, I was offline. So did you get answers to all your questions?

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty yea, the problem was in the definition for me, it's the first time I learned what discriminant really means, thank you very much