# How many days are needed to find the robot?

Tags: puzzle

There is a row of $n$ opaque boxes numbered from $1$ to $n$.

A robot is programmed with an ordered pair of numbers $(x,y)$, each being integers between $1$ and $n$, inclusive.

$x$ is the box the robot will be in on the first day, and $y$ is the "speed" of the robot: each night the robot adds $y$ to its current box number and moves to that new box. If the sum exceeds $n$, then the robot subtracts $n$ to determine its new box.

You may open one box per day. How many days are needed to guarantee finding the robot? More specifically, is there a formula (explicit or recursive) based on $n$?

I've made only a little progress working by hand.

| Number of boxes, $n$ | Days to find the robot |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $1$ |
| $2$ | $3$ |
| $3$ | $4$ |
| $4$ | $5$ |

For $n=3$ my solution is $1,1,3,2$. For $n=4$ my solution is $1,4,3,4,2$. For $n=5$ the best I can do is $9$ days, but I'm not confident about that being optimal.

These came from using a greedy algorithm like approach: I listed out all the possible sequences of the robot's positions and on each day looked for which box I could open that would eliminate most of the remaining sequences.

I tried searching $1,3,4,5,9$ in OEIS and it came back with these so-called [Stone Skipping Numbers](https://oeis.org/A136259). I don't fully understand what the comments mean, but it seems to not be analogous to my box problem.

EDIT/UPDATE:

For $n=6$ boxes, I found a solution of $9$ days, which is: $1,2,6,5,4,4,3,4,2$.

I also know that if $n$ is a prime number, then the robot can be found in at most $2n-1$ days by the following process: Open box #$1$ on each of the first $n$ days. This will capture all robots except the ones that are stationary in the other boxes. Then open boxes $2$ through $n$ on days $n+1$ through $2n-1$.

Comment: See N. S. (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9176/n-s), Progressions modulo $n$, URL (version: 2016-07-16): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1861219

Comment: I don’t think there’s any reason why a nice formula should exist – given the setting, the arithmetic properties of $n$ intervene too messily and the CRT doesn’t even manage to properly decompose the problem (you need strategies for different prime powers that manage to simultaneously make the correct guesses [!]) – so the function is “sub-multiplicative” (yet not multiplicative, as your finding with $6$ proves). When $n$ is a power of the prime $p$, $2n-1$ guesses should work as well (same overall strategy, but the second step serves to meet the walks by steps divisible by $p$).

Comment: Also, I think your solution for $n=3$ doesn’t find the robot whose moves are $3,2,1,3$… and for $n=6$, you don’t catch the robot doing $6,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4$, do you? Same for $n=4$ and $4,3,2,1,4$…

Comment: This idea of +50 bounty followed by +100 bounty is awesome. I'll be sure to apply it on my questions.

Comment: Oh dang, yeah my solutions don't work for $n=3$ or $n=6$. The $2n-1$ strategy works for 3 boxes though. @mathlander I don't understand? this is the first bounty I put on this question.

Comment: Oops, I messed up. The +50 was on a related question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution for n=3 is wrong. This table shows, which robot you will find on which day.

| day | box | (1,1) | (1,2) | (1,3) | (2,1) | (2,2) | (2,3) | (3,1) | (3,2) | (3,3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x | x | x |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |  | x |  | x |  | x |  |  |
| 3 | 3 | x |  |  |  | x |  |  |  | x |
| 4 | 2 |  |  |  | x | x | x |  |  |  |

There is no day on which you find robot (3,2). There is no solution with 4 days. The shortest solution is 5 days long. There are many 5-day-solutions, here is one of them:

| day | box | (1,1) | (1,2) | (1,3) | (2,1) | (2,2) | (2,3) | (3,1) | (3,2) | (3,3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x | x | x |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | x |  |  |  |  | x |  | x |  |
| 3 | 3 | x |  |  |  | x |  |  |  | x |
| 4 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x |
| 5 | 3 |  | x |  | x |  |  |  |  | x |

Your solution for n=4 is also wrong:

| day | box | (1,1) | (1,2) | (1,3) | (1,4) | (2,1) | (2,2) | (2,3) | (2,4) | (3,1) | (3,2) | (3,3) | (3,4) | (4,1) | (4,2) | (4,3) | (4,4) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x | x | x | x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 4 |  |  | x |  |  | x |  |  | x |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |
| 3 | 3 | x |  | x |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |  | x |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 4 | x |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |  |  | x |
| 5 | 2 |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

There are even 3 robots you don't find: (4,1), (4,2) and (4,3)

Here is a solution with 7 days:

| day | box | (1,1) | (1,2) | (1,3) | (1,4) | (2,1) | (2,2) | (2,3) | (2,4) | (3,1) | (3,2) | (3,3) | (3,4) | (4,1) | (4,2) | (4,3) | (4,4) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x | x | x | x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | x |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |  |  | x |  |  | x |  |  |
| 3 | 3 | x |  | x |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |  | x |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 4 | x |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |  |  | x |  |  |  |  | x |
| 5 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | x | x | x | x |
| 6 | 4 |  |  | x |  |  | x |  |  | x |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |
| 7 | 4 |  |  |  |  | x |  | x |  |  |  |  |  |  | x |  | x |

I did not find any shorter solution for n=4.

My best solution for n=5 needs also 9 days, but again your solution for n=6 is wrong. The table would be too big (it would have 38 columns), so I don't show it here, but your solution doesn't find the robot (6,5). So you need one more day to find this robot,
which means, that you need 10 days for n=6. (I found a lot of other solutions with 10 days, but no solution with less than 10 days.)

My best solution for n=8 needs 15 days: 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8. For n=9 I found a solution with 17 days: 1, 2, 3, 9, 6, 5, 8, 1, 1, 7, 5, 9, 3, 9, 4, 5, 7 and for n=10 with 19 days: 1, 10, 2, 9, 6, 3, 7, 4, 3, 2, 9, 5, 8, 2, 4, 2, 9, 9, 8

So, for now we have:

| n | days |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 10 |
| 7 | 13 |
| 8 | 15 |
| 9 | 17 |
| 10 | 19 |
| 11 | 21 |

You already found an upper boundary for n=prime, and I think for prime numbers this is even the best solution. So, it looks, as if the formula was just $2n-1$, except for n=6.

This is not a full solution, but I hope it helps you a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for your work on this. With $n=6$ having a $10$ day solution, now I am curious if $n=12$ will also break the $2n-1$ pattern? I can try by hand to find that solution.

Comment: In my first attempt at $n=12$ I found a $23$ day solution, which is: 1,2,4,11,3,12,10,1,2,3,11,2,5,10,10,6,12,9,7,5,8,4,3. My method is just seeing at each day which box holds the most robots of all possible sequences. I may try again later.

Comment: For $n=12$ I found a $21$ day solution: 1, 5, 6, 8, 12, 7, 9, 10, 2, 11, 3, 4, 7, 1, 12, 2, 6, 10, 3, 9, 8.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proof that the optimal answer for $n = p$ prime is $2p - 1$.

If we open box $a_i$ on day $i$, then to find the robot in $t$ days we need
$$\prod_{i = 1}^t (x + iy - a_i) = 0$$
for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{F}_p^2$. So the polynomial on LHS must be identically zero on $\mathbb{F}_p^2$, which is equivalent to the fact that the polynomial is zero in the ring $\mathbb{F}_p[x, y] / (x^p - x, y^p - y)$.

It is clearly impossible that $t < p$. Now suppose $p \leq t < 2p - 1$. We consider the coefficient of the monomial $x^{t - p + 1} y^{p - 1}$ in the standard basis $\{x^i y^j: (i, j) \in [0, p - 1]^2\}$ of $\mathbb{F}_p[x, y] / (x^p - x, y^p - y)$. By degree counting(the crucial observation is that $t - p + 1 \leq p - 1$, so only monomials with degree $t$ or higher would contribute to the coefficient of this monomial), the coefficient of $x^{t - p + 1} y^{p - 1}$ is equal to its coefficient in
$$\prod_{i = 1}^t (x + iy) = (x^{p - 1} - y^{p - 1})x\prod_{i = 1}^{t - p} (x + iy)$$
which is the nonzero $-1$, contradiction. So we must have $t \geq 2p - 1$.

Comment: Great argument! Now I wonder if this still holds when $n$ is a prime power…

Comment: I thought about it a bit, but even $n = p^2$ seems much harder.

Comment: Sad to say this is over my head, but it's nice to know a proof exists for $2n-1$ being optimal for $n$ being a prime number. What is meant by $\Bbb{F}_p^2$?

Comment: Oh it is just the set of $(x, y)$ modulo $p$.